# How do I quickly convert DataTable to IList<myType>

Tags: c#, wpf, list, datatable, ienumerable

In my sample, i tried to view the pivotal information in Grid control with given items source. In this case to pass the items source, i need to convert the `DataTable` into `IList<myType>` in C#.

I have tried all the traditional conversion methods including the below code to convert the `DataTable` into `IList`.

```
dt.AsEnumerable().Cast<object>().ToList()
```

But the all the traditional  methods are not helpful for me since, i don't know exactly what are the objects are used and their types in respective columns in `DataTable`. Also the `DataTable` having more number of columns and rows.

For example, I am having the below column values in my data table.

```
PlanRowPID,PlanRowClass,PlanRowVendor,PlanRowColor
PID 0,CLASS 8,VENDOR A,COLOR D
PID 1,CLASS 7,VENDOR B,COLOR C
PID 2,CLASS 9,VENDOR C,COLOR B
PID 3,CLASS 6,VENDOR D,COLOR B
```

And finally i want to do the following pro-grammatically,

```
IList<myType> list = new IList<myType>;
list.Add(new myType() {PlanRowPID = "PID 0",PlanRowClass = "CLASS 8",PlanRowVendor = "VENDOR A",PlanRowColor=COLOR D});
list.Add(new myType() {PlanRowPID = "PID 1",PlanRowClass = "CLASS 7",PlanRowVendor = "VENDOR B",PlanRowColor=COLOR C});
list.Add(new myType() {PlanRowPID = "PID 2",PlanRowClass = "CLASS 9",PlanRowVendor = "VENDOR C",PlanRowColor=COLOR B});
```

In my application I have more than 10000 data columns, so it is not possible to add each and every object from data table into list.I need to spend more time and knowledge to find the data type of each columns available in `DataTable` and then create the properties based on their types for `myType` class.

So please provide any optimal and quickest way to convert the `DataTable` into `IList<myType>`.

Comment: Have you tried using an ORM like Entity Framework?

Comment: Yes, but ORM is helpful only if i having less number of entities. In case i am having more number of entities, it is hard to create the class with finding the data type of each columns. I need the programmatic way to find the type and create the class efficiently.

Comment: Can you talk us through why you have 10,000 columns?

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/101827/6172

Answer (score 1):

Please try,

```
private static List<T> ConvertDataTable<T>(DataTable dt)  
{  
    List<T> data = new List<T>();  
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)  
    {  
        T item = GetItem<T>(row);  
        data.Add(item);  
    }  
    return data;  
} 

private static T GetItem<T>(DataRow dr)  
{  
    Type temp = typeof(T);  
    T obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();  

    foreach (DataColumn column in dr.Table.Columns)  
    {  
        foreach (PropertyInfo pro in temp.GetProperties())  
        {  
            if (pro.Name == column.ColumnName)  
                pro.SetValue(obj, dr[column.ColumnName], null);  
            else  
                continue;  
        }  
    }  
    return obj;  
}
```

Example to invoke,

```
List<Student> studentDetails = new List<Student>();  
studentDetails = ConvertDataTable<Student>(dt);
```

Source :- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ee01e6/different-way-to-convert-datatable-to-list/

Comment: Thanks. But my actual problem is, how the class "Student" is defined with initializing the properties obtained from each data table row. Is there any pro grammatical way exist for defined the class with initializing the properties available in data table?. For my example, I need to create the class "Plan" with "PlanRowPID", "PlanRowClass", etc., pro-grammatically.

Answer (score 1):

> In this case to pass the items source, i need to convert the `DataTable` into `IList` in C#.

Can't you just set the `ItemsSource` property to the `DefaultView` of the `DataTable`?

```
dataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

Then there is no need to convert it to a list.

`DataView` implements `IList`.